# Different Directives with Common HTML / JavaScript Parts - Best Practices

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my application I can create new forms by creating directives. These directives/forms can be configured to be used by some parts on my site.

Now all of these forms should have two buttons to save/cancel all changes. So every form has a (breeze) DataContext and these buttons with their event-handlers.

What I would like to do, is "inherit" the HTML for the buttons and the JavaScript-Code for the event-handlers (and the DataContext) and also be able to override/extend the event-handlers to do something additional in a concrete form if necessary.

What would be the best practice to do this? I thought about the following ways but they don't seem very practical:

- Create a "Base"-Directive which transcludes the configured concrete form directive. This would mean, that when I want to use one of the forms, I would have to use the "Base"-Directive and configure it to use the concrete form.
- Inside my "Concrete"-Directive, use the "Base"-Directive to add the functionality. This would mean, that to override one of the event-handlers I need to know the directive in JavaScript - which isn't so easy (the "require" only works in the parent direction).

I also thought about sharing the $scope or controller by passing it in as an attribute to one or the other and using a Service to "initialize" all the directives' $scopes with the handler functions. But this also seems a bit dirty.

The best solution for me would be, if I could just use any of the forms directives directly, without having to think about the buttons etc. And when I create a new forms-directive, I could just tell it what to "inherit" from and in case I need to do something special in the "save" or "cancel" event-handlers, to be able to override it.

Is that somehow possible?

Comment: What I do in this scenario (this is just personal preference), I pass the functions to my Directive. For example, I have a 'Save' button Directive I use across my apps. This has an 'OnClick' attribute, and I pass a method to handle this from my Controller. Inside my Directive I make sure it is in fact a method and invoke it when the Directive's click event triggers. I do the same for other events I want to handle (I have an 'OnError') and the same to deal with callbacks and promises.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. How would you do the communication from the form to the save-button (for example to tell it to save without the button clicked)? I thought about that and I think that would mean the Savebutton-Directive needed some "onLoaded"-Handler which passes the directives-Controller back up to the form. How do you solve this?

Comment: Well, your directive is going to have a function that will save for instance. This function can be triggered by anything really. You can then create a directive scope that you will bind to the form. Then from the form you can call this method whenever you need to. I will try to come up with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little example that will call a `saveForm` method in the directive. This method listens to a `save-form` being triggered by anything using the directive:

**JS**:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';    
    angular
        .module("myApp", [])
        .directive("saveButton", [function () {
         return {
             restrict: 'E',
             scope: {},
             template: "<input type='button' value='Save' />",
             link: function(scope) {
                 //expose the method to the outside world
                 scope.saveForm = saveForm;

                 //listen to the broadcast
                scope.$on("save-form", function () {
                  scope.saveForm();
                });

             }
         }

         function saveForm() {
             alert("Now I am saving");
         }
        }]);

    angular
        .module("myApp")
        .controller("myController", myController);

    //inject $scope to call $broadcast
    myController.$inject = ["$scope"];

    function myController($scope) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.text = "Save will be triggered on blur...";

        vm.doSave = function() {
            $scope.$broadcast("save-form");
        }
    }
})();
```

**View**:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController as vm">
        <form>

            <save-button ng-click='vm.doSave()'></save-button>
            <input type="text" value="{{ vm.text }}" ng-blur="vm.doSave()" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/k7yjkvk6/

Now, if your forms all save in a different way, you could provide your directive with the method it needs to save that specific form:

**JS**:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';    
    angular
        .module("myApp", [])
        .directive("saveButton", [function () {
         return {
             restrict: 'E',
             scope: {
                mySaveFunction: "="
             },
             template: "<input type='button' value='Save' />",
             link: function(scope) {
                 //expose the method to the outside world     
                 //listen to the broadcast
                scope.$on("save-form", function () {
                    if(typeof scope.mySaveFunction === "function")
                    {
                        scope.mySaveFunction.call();
                    }
                });

             }
         }
        }]);

    angular
        .module("myApp")
        .controller("myController", myController);

    //inject $scope to call $broadcast
    myController.$inject = ["$scope"];

    function myController($scope) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.text = "Save will be triggered on blur...";

        vm.doSave = function() {
            $scope.$broadcast("save-form");
        }

        vm.thisFormsSave = function() {
            alert("I save the way I want!");
        }
    }
})();
```

**View**:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController as vm">
        <form>

            <save-button ng-click='vm.doSave()' my-save-function="vm.thisFormsSave"></save-button>
            <input type="text" value="{{ vm.text }}" ng-blur="vm.doSave()" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that this way I changed nothing on the textbox, and it still saves using the new function.

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/k7yjkvk6/1/

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort! In my attempt in the meanwhile I chose the second example you described. It allowed me to do some generic stuff for every form and also pass a handler for some specific logic.

Comment: @NoRyb I am glad it helped. Good luck.